# Crear condición dependiendo el porcentaje

Tags: php, html, css

Buenas comunidad me gustaría recibir su apoyo con una duda que tengo y siento que me eh cerrado y no encuentro como hacerlo. actualmente tengo un programa que lleva el porcentaje de tareas realizadas por dias. hecho en php me gustaria que cuando el % sea cero mostrar un texto que diga en proceso. y cuando llegue al 100% diga proceso completado.

```
<?php 
    $total   = substr($user->finish, 0, 4)  - substr($user->start, 0, 4) + 1;
    $current = substr($user->diasf, 0, 4);
    $percent = ($current/$total) * 100;
    $percent = round($percent, 0); 
    ?>

 <div class="barra" style="background: #EEE; width: 100%; height: 20px; position: relative;">
                          <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped progress-bar-animated progreso" style="height: 100%; width: <?= $percent ?>%; "><?php echo $percent ?>%<div class="porcentaje"></div>
                          </div>
                        </div>
```

si pudieran lograr apoyarme estaría agradecido.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Crea una variable que se llame $estado y colocas la condicion que necesitas e imprimes dentro del div esa variable

Comment: ya eso se me ocurrio pero realmente no se me ocurre como crear la condicion si  tienes la idea como te lo agradeceria josue.

Comment: ya te doy un ejemplo

Comment: Checa este ejemplo https://3v4l.org/s9skJ#v8.1rc3

Comment: En una variable depende del porcentaje coloco un nombre y ese mismo valor lo puedes colocar en **<?php echo $percent ?>** para que diga que esta listo o terminado

Comment: josue vargas aplique el codigo que tu me mostraste y obtengo el resultado que quiero en parte. porque solo me muestra el mensaje de completado pero no el de en proceso.

` <!-- <?php 
        $total   = substr($user->finish, 0, 4)  - substr($user->start, 0, 4) + 1;
        $current = substr($user->diasf, 0, 4);
        $percent = ($current/$total) * 100;
        $percent = round($percent, 0); 


        $estado = $percent==0?"En Proceso":"";
        echo $estado;
        
    
        $estado = $percent==100?"Completado":"";
        echo $estado;
?> -->
realize una edicion

Comment: Porque te falta el ELSE coloca **Completado":"PENDIENTE";** y listo

Comment: Me confirmas si te sirve

Comment: nose algo estoy haciendo mal porque si detallas la foto los dos completados que me muestra abajo no corresponde a los de arriba. osea en la tabla de abajo deberia tener completado las dos primeras lineas y no la segunda y la tercera.

Comment: Recuerda que es un simple **IF** *SI VALOR == "ALGO" ? "ENTONCES ESTO":"SI NO ESTO";* espero entiendas la lógica con esto :)

Comment: acabo de hacer una edición a la pregunta. ya logre el resultado que deseaba muchas gracias por el apoyo a ti jouse y a la comunidad. por el apoyo.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar un switch para evaluar tu variable $percent, y usar echo para mostrar la barra de progreso

```
<?php 
    /*$total   = substr($user->finish, 0, 4)  - substr($user->start, 0, 4) + 1;
    $current = substr($user->diasf, 0, 4);
    $percent = ($current/$total) * 100;
    $percent = round($percent, 0); */

    $percent = 100;
    //Switch que evalua la variable $percent
    switch ($percent) {
        case 0:
            echo '
            <div class="progress">
              <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped progress-bar-animated" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="0" style="width: 100%;" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100">'.'%'.$percent.' En proceso</div>
            </div>
            ';
            break;
        case 100:
            echo '
            <div class="progress">
              <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped progress-bar-animated" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="0" style="width: 100%;" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100">'.'%'.$percent.' Completado</div>
            </div>
            ';
            break;
        default:
            // code...
            break;
    }
    ?>
```